# Proper Order to Process Each Frame

Tags: physics, graphics, sound, control

I'm writing a rudimentary 2D engine and am wondering what the proper or generally accepted order is for handling graphics, user input, sounds, and then other systems like physics.

If you have written an engine, please explain your order and why you picked that particular order.

Comment: What is the main issue with the order you already have chosen?

Comment: I'm mostly looking to see what others have done to maintain responsiveness and still get the job done. I'm new to the game design thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, you'll go by logic wiht what needs first to be done for the subsequent steps.

1. **Input**
2. **Logic pre-physics** -- react to user input and prepare stuff for your...
3. **Physics simulation** -- Physics engine update here
4. **Logic post-physics** -- Stuff that needs to be done in reaction to the physics simulation, namely trigger reaction, graphics positioning w.r.t. physics, etc...
5. **Render/sound** -- they're the result of the current simulation frame.

Comment: I didn't even think about pre/post physics. Thanks!

Comment: If you're going that way (pre and post physics updates), don't just call one of your updates *update* as you'll get lost as to which does this represent.. pre or post? Be descriptive, otherwise you'll hate yourself after a while.

Comment: Yeah, I've learned better than to have bland, generic names.